# How can I do a merge of two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with schemas like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordsA] (
    [WordId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
    [FromWordA] BIT NULL,
    [FromWordB] BIT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordsB] (
    [WordId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

How can I take the contents of table WordsB and insert into WordsA row by row:

If Word does not exist in WordsA

```
Insert into WordsA and set FromWordB = 1
```

If Word exists in WordsA

```
Update WordsA setting FromWordB = 1
```

Comment: Have you searched SO for the 6th word in your title? "merge [sql-server]" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need MERGE:

```
MERGE [dbo].[WordsA] as target
USING [dbo].[WordsB] as source
ON target.[Word] = source.[Word] 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [FromWordB] = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([Word],[FromWordA],[FromWordb]) 
    VALUES (source.[Word],0,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try (not tested):

```
MERGE WordsA A
    USING       WordsB      B
    ON          A.WordId = B.WordID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
                INSERT (Word, FromWordB)
                VALUES (B.Word, 1)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE SET FromWordB = 1
;
```